# How to hide wordpress error from a non logged guest rather to show 404 error while trying wp-admin?

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, http-status-code-404

I am designing my wordpress website and nobody should know that I am using wordpress for my site. I designed my custom login page with custom URL and managed my logged in users to get HTTP 404 error if they try to access wp-admin or wp-login but only thing left is that if a guest who is not logged in try to access wp admin by simply typing www.mydomain/wp-admin on browser gets wordpress error which reveals everything. So I need a code so those guests also get HTTP 404 error. They should be redirected 404 page only because I set a ban for those users who get more than 5 HTTP error. Anyone please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Lockdown WP](http://wordpress.org/plugins/lockdown-wp-admin/) plugin to hide the /wp-admin section and return a 404 error for users that are not logged in. It will also rewrite the login as you have already done.

Keep in mind that there are still many give-aways that you are using Wordpress, such as the wp-content folder and other telltale files, if people actually want to find out what you are running.

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply. I was searching for this I will definitely try this. And about wp-content, I  renamed it using better wp security plugin and also renamed wp-login. what else shall I do please suggest.

Comment: Many of the cookies are WP specific, as well as CSS classes.